# Get Table and Count in each Table of dataset in BigQuery

Tags: sql, group-by, count, dataset, google-bigquery

I want to understand how to get count of each table in dataset. I think I can get sum of counts in all tables by this query

```
SELECT count(*) FROM `DATASET.*`
```

How can I group it by each table and get the count?

Comment: Agree with duplicate vote, but just for OP in case it's not clear: `SELECT
  table_id,
  row_count
FROM
  project.dataset.__TABLES__`

Comment: Thanks Graham Polley

Comment: @Graham Polley  : What is the difference between 1. SELECT sum(row_count) FROM BenchmarkBench.__TABLES__ 

2. select count(*) from `BenchmarkBench.*`  -- As these give different counts when I run

Comment: 1 = sum all the rows across all tables, 2 = # of rows returned i.e. # tables

Comment: Graham Polley Thanks for your explanation. Sorry I didn't get the difference. Can you please elaborate. I think it should return the same value.

Comment: No, it won't: `sum()` and `count()` do different things! Here you go - https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_count_avg_sum.asp

Comment: @Graham Polley I am summing the row_count above and I think it should give the same count. I

Comment: Sorry, I can't explain it any better than what I've already tried. Maybe someone else can explain the difference between `sum` and `count` better than me.